# Query the results of another query

Tags: sql

I'm writing a query to build an audience for a abandoned cart email. So far, I have the script below, which gives me the correct result (as far as I can tell). However, if possible I would like to query the final result, in order to:

- Check if there are multiples of the same `email_address` that exist in the
  output
- If true, select the `email_address` with the **oldest** (min) `modified_date`

`email_address` exist in table **a**, but I want to use the `modified_date` from table **c**.

Can anybody assist me?

Also, I'm not an sql dev, so if you could please explain your answer to help me learn, I would grateful.

Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.guid,
                a.customer_id,
                a.email_address,
                c.product_code,
                c.purchase_url,
                c.modified_date
FROM   (SELECT LIST.guid,
               LIST.customer_id,
               LIST.email_address
        FROM   $a$ LIST) a
       INNER JOIN (SELECT BASE.guid
                   FROM   $b$ BASE) b
               ON a.guid = b.guid
       INNER JOIN (SELECT SUPP.customer_id,
                          SUPP.product_code,
                          SUPP.purchase_url,
                          SUPP.modified_date
                   FROM   $c$ SUPP) c
               ON a.customer_id = c.customer_id
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT EXCL.product_code
                  FROM   $d$ EXCL) d
              ON c.product_code = d.product_code
WHERE  d.product_code IS NULL
       AND c.product_code IS NOT NULL
       AND c.modified_date = (SELECT Max(J.modified_date)
                              FROM   $c$ J
                              WHERE  J.customer_id = c.customer_id)
       AND Trunc(c.modified_date) = Trunc(sysdate) - 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need email_address with mininum modified_date you can use below query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.guid,
                a.customer_id,
                a.email_address,
                c.product_code,
                c.purchase_url,
                min(c.modified_date)over(partition by a.email_address)modified_date
FROM   (SELECT LIST.guid,
               LIST.customer_id,
               LIST.email_address
        FROM   $a$ LIST) a
       INNER JOIN (SELECT BASE.guid
                   FROM   $b$ BASE) b
               ON a.guid = b.guid
       INNER JOIN (SELECT SUPP.customer_id,
                          SUPP.product_code,
                          SUPP.purchase_url,
                          SUPP.modified_date
                   FROM   $c$ SUPP) c
               ON a.customer_id = c.customer_id
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT EXCL.product_code
                  FROM   $d$ EXCL) d
              ON c.product_code = d.product_code
WHERE  d.product_code IS NULL
       AND c.product_code IS NOT NULL
       AND c.modified_date = (SELECT Max(J.modified_date)
                              FROM   $c$ J
                              WHERE  J.customer_id = c.customer_id)
       AND Trunc(c.modified_date) = Trunc(sysdate) - 1
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. This works great, but I need all columns from the original query.

Comment: I have changed my answer. I used windows function instead of outer query. Please check. Or you need to use group by  on a.guid,
                a.customer_id,
                a.email_address,
                c.product_code, and
                c.purchase_url?

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly!! I didn't realise you could do it that way. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Please check out this link to have a look in more window functions https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/

Comment: Brilliant. Will study this for future needs. Thanks again.

Comment: You will love these. Best wishes.